# Finding proper hook for a major mode

Tags: latex, hooks

So this is some elisp code I have in my `init.el` file:

```
(defun complete-dollar () 
  (interactive)
  (insert "$$")
  (backward-char 1))

(defun my-latex-keys ()
  "Modify keymaps by latex-mode"
  (local-set-key (kbd "$") 'complete-dollar))

(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'my-latex-keys)
```

Now, I open a tex file to test it. And when I type a `$` it just gives
me `$` instead of `$$` as expected from the above elisp code. This is
the value for the major-mode variable in the buffer:

> major-mode: latex-mode

Also the key `$` is binded to `autopair-insert-or-skip-paired-delimiter` when I inspect it. Any
reason on why it's not working ? (Also, if my elisp code isn't the
correct way of doing this, I would love to know the recommended
approach)

**Edit:**
Ok, this made it to work:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'sibi-latex-keys)
```

So my question is how to find which hook is the approriate one out of the following choices:

- latex-mode-hook
- LaTeX-mode-hook
- tex-mode-hook

Comment: The one you selected is for the `AUCTeX` package which inherits the other modes from `tex-mode.el` and then changes stuff.  The `AUCTeX` package is not a part of the basic Emacs installation.  The basic installation of Emacs just comes with the library `tex-mode.el`.  You can take a look at the `tex-mode.el` library by typing:  `M-x find-library RET tex-mode RET`.  The other two hooks are primarily used when **not** using the AUCTex package.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. Is there any formal way of finding out the proper hook from the current buffer using any variables or so ?

Comment: I think just about every user of the AUCTeX package has struggled with what you just went through (including me at the outset of my Emacs journey) -- except of course, those scholarly individuals who sit down and read everything there is to know about the AUCTeX package before trying to use it.  What you did is completely appropriate and is usually sufficient -- i.e., `M-x describe-mode RET`.  If it were me designing a package, I would do more than just change the upper/lower case of a mode-name -- I would probably have called it something different entirely.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. In that case, can you post your comment as an answer ?

Comment: After a brief grepping of the AUCTeX source code, it is not as straight-forward as I had thought in terms of what portions of the `tex-mode.el` library are still utilized by AUCTeX.  Here is a link to the AUCTeX manual regarding the basic hooks used by that library:  https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html  I would need to spend additional time grepping and reviewing the source code in order to better understand what portions of the `tex-mode.el` library are utilized by the AUCTeX package.  I'm not comfortable with my present limited knowledge to post an answer.

Comment: AUCTeX has already this feature: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html#index-TeX_002delectric_002dmath

Comment: Recent GNU AUCTeX versions already have the feature you are looking for. Have a look at the customize option `TeX-electric-math`.